# Email Subscriptions not working

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tableau-crm

I've a Tableau CRM (Einstein Analytics) Dashboard that runs on different recipes. After subscribing to a widget, the Subscription Emails are not delivered as scheduled. But when I click Save and Run to evaluate the subscription, I get the email with the attachment(s).

I have created a PS and assigned the necessary permissions required to subscribe to widgets/lenses and download the data. As per SFDC documentation, these are the two permissions required to subscribe to a widget:

Subscribe to Email Notifications:

```
    1. UseSubscriptionEmails (Subscribe to CRM Analytics Assets)
    2. WaveTabularDownload (Download CRM Analytics Data) - for the attachments
```

- Access Level for Email Deliverability is set to `All Email`.
- `Receive Salesforce CRM Content Email Alerts` is true in user record.
- I have set the subscription time in GMT so that I should get the mail at the expected time.
- `Enable CRM Analytics Custom Time Zone Support` is unchecked in `Analytics Settings`.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks